# Spring 3 component-scan with duplicate package structures

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jar

I am currently changing an older (2.x) Spring web mvc application that used SimpleFormController to now use Spring 3.2.13 and to be annotation driven. This is a stepping stone to get to Spring 4. The web application has a dependent jar file that has several Controllers within it. I've annotated the Controllers in the jar file but the component scanning does not pick them up. I believe the root cause of the issue is that the WEB-INF/classes directory has the same root package structure as the jar file.

For example, in WEB-INF/classes I have a controller:

```
com.myapp.common.package1.ControllerA
```

and in the jar file I have a second controller:

```
com.myapp.common.package2.ControllerB
```

In my servlet's context file I have:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    .... 
</beans>
```

The ControllerB class does not get detected by Spring. The Jar File uses directory entries and if I add another controller to the jar file that has a different package structure (e.g. com.myapp.mvc.ControllerC) Spring detects it.

I'm guessing since Spring has already scanned one directory structure under WEB-INF/classes (com.myapp.common), it is ignoring similar directory structures in the jar file. Is my assumption correct? Is there a way to tell Spring to scan similar directory entries that have different roots in the classpath? Some options I think I have are to:

1. Change the package structure of the controllers in the either the web application or the depended on project that generates the jar.
2. Unpack the jar file into the classes directory of the web application.
3. Add the classes from the web application to the jar file.

Before I went down one of those roads I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing
something simple. Thank you.

Comment: When you say base-package is `com.myapp`, it will start at this package and scan all sub-folders and register any bean with proper annotations, so that shouldn't be a problem. Where's your JAR containing 2nd controller ? Is it inside WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: Yes it is in WEB-INF/lib. Spring will find other controllers in the same jar file as long as their package structure differs from the controllers under WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: The controllers which are not registered by Spring, do they have @Controller annotation on top of the class ?

Comment: Yes it does. I just tried a test where I moved the Controller that gets bundled in the jar to a different package (e.g. com.myapp.test.ControllerB) and Spring loaded it. All I did was move it. Instead of moving the Controllers in the Jar file though, I think I may just move them to a separate WAR file and then use that as an overlay (via maven) to all the legacy Web applications.

Comment: That's strange if you have classes in right place with right annotation, then it should work. Do you see any exceptions ?

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a large modular application with each module in an overlay. The JSP and controllers in these modules are not getting recognized by spring Component scan. Each of these Overlay projects are working fine, but when I bundle them, the inner overlay components (controllers) are not getting recognized. Issue with Spring or Maven (overlay) ???

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know exactly your use-case, I might be wrong but usually all Controllers are part of a WAR/EAR file. Not sure why you would want to bundle a Controller in a JAR file.

Comment: The reason is that this is part of a suite of legacy web applications that share a set of common controllers and that's why they were packaged in a jar. Another solution I think would be to move the common controllers into a Base WAR project and use Maven's overlay functionality to apply the common controllers to all the web applications.